# 13.04 - more than four workspace shortcuts in GNOME Flashback (No effects)

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I'm using GNOME Flashback (No effects) on Ubuntu 13.04 and I've got six workspaces however when entering System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Navigation I only see options to address the initial four.

It used to be options up to 12 workspaces there and as I certainly don't need that much, I want to have at least enough for the amount currently active.

How can I restore or add more shotcuts specifically to navigate and move windows to workspace 5 and 6?

Answer (score 32):

The only way I have found to modify the keyboard shortcuts for workspaces 5 and up in GNOME Flashback, is through a shell using the `dconf` command.

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-1
['<Primary>F1']
```

Here I read the shortcut setting for the first workspace, to get an idea about the syntax to use when setting values for the missing shortcuts. I'm using `CTRL`+ `F1` myself.

To add shortcuts for the remaining workspaces, just modify the value returned above to match the workspace number, and use `dconf`to apply them:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-5 "['<Primary>F5']"
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-6 "['<Primary>F6']"
```

Comment: works on 15.04 as well, thank you

Comment: Aha, there they are! Can somebody explain why the answer with -1 votes is above the *correct* answer with 6 votes?

Comment: Years later, works on 18.04!

Answer (score 11):

Maybe a slightly more comfortable way then using dconf on the command line is dconf-editor. Run dconf-editor and then navigate to

org -> gnome -> desktop ->wm ->keybindings

There you can find and edit the switch-to-workspace and move-to-workspace commands for workspaces 1 through 9.

Comment: Works in Debian 10. Thanks!

Comment: works on Ubunutu 21.04

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to add more shortcuts but you can use alt+ctrl+right/left arrow to move between the workspaces

(and you can use alt+ctrl+shift+right/left arrows to move windows to other workspaces)

I always use those

Comment: I use those but I also like to jump to a specific one, thanks anyway.