# GNOME - How to adress a shortcut for workspace 5+?

Tags: gnome, workspaces, shortcuts

I would like to know how I can address shortcuts for more than 4 workspaces in GNOME.

Unfortunately, I can only see 4 entries for the workspace 1-4 in the  keyboard settings.

[image]

I would like to switch to workspace 5 when I press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. It already works for the Workspaces 1-4.

It is possible to create a new shortcut, but I don't know the command which I have to use.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/332264/13-04-more-than-four-workspace-shortcuts-in-gnome-flashback-no-effects

Comment: @heynnema Thank you very much, this worked for me

Comment: You're very welcome. Tell me though... why do you need to access more than 4 workspaces? Inquiring minds want to know :-) Can you really being doing so much *at the same time* that would require that?

Comment: I'm using certain workspaces for different applications. For example workspace 1 is always my browser and 2 is always email. It is very handy, because you know always which button you have to press to get to your wished application. So my standard programms alone use 3 workspaces :-)

Comment: Just to answer the "why so many?" question: I have the first for my browser, then one for each project I'm working on. Sadly I have to work across seven or eight projects in my job, so I need a lot of workspaces. When a query comes in I can flip immediately to a desktop with everything set up ready to fix the problem. Very handy!